# Push failed: Could not get a logplex token for this app

Tags: git, heroku, github, token

I am trying to follow the SFDC Integration Workbook. http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/integration_workbook/integration_workbook.pdf

I got stuck on Tutorial #1 Step: 4: To deploy the local code to Heroku, execute the following command: git push heroku master

I get this error:

```
!     Push failed: Could not get a logplex token for this app. Please try the request again.
!     If the problem persists, see http://help.heroku.com and provide Request ID b6b5a577-2056- 4956-addb-8649abfaef2d.


To git@heroku.com:young-sierra-3666.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:young-sierra-3666.git'
```

I have worked with Rails+Heroku, but this Tutorial uses Java Spring MVC framework...any idea of what is happening?

For some reason my app seams to be created...

```
$ heroku info
=== young-sierra-3666
Git URL:       git@heroku.com:young-sierra-3666.git
Owner Email:   lutgardo21@gmail.com
Region:        us
Stack:         cedar
Web URL:       http://young-sierra-3666.herokuapp.com/
```

But does not appears on Heroku Dashboard

Comment: From the error, there's a `pre-receive` hook in the git server, which rejected your `push`. You may check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That may be a temporary issue, as the [status.heroku.com](https://status.heroku.com/) site does mention ([incident 167](https://status.heroku.com/incidents/667)):

> We are seeing an issue Logplex drain management and tail sessions.
>   Customers are seeing "! **Could not create Logplex session**. Please try again later."
>   error for heroku logs command, for new drain creation or removing it. The existing drains are not affected. We continue to investigate.